# What's the difference between .ToConstructor and .ToMethod in Ninject 3?

Tags: c#, ninject

In Ninject3 there's a new [.ToConstructor feature](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/).

As described, it helps to strongly-type constructor arguments like:

```
Bind<IMyService>().ToConstructor(
    ctorArg => new MyService(ctorArg.Inject<IFoo>(), ctorArg.Inject<IBar>()));
```

What's actually the difference between using *.ToConstructor* and *.ToMethod* in an almost the same way:

```
Bind<IMyService>().ToMethod(
    x => new MyService(x.Kernel.Get<IFoo>(), x.Kernel.Get<IBar>()));
```

Is it just a syntax sugar to avoid using *Kernel.Get<>()* or is there something more that I'm missing?

Comment: Note: `Get<T>` is an extension method and you must be `using Ninject;` for it to work. It took me a minute because I have got away with `using Ninject.Modulesl` until now )

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first case behaves like `To<MyService>()` except that you explicitly select the constructor. This means the context is passed through `MyService` and you can use conditions for `IFoo` and `IBar` or one of their dpependencies where in the second case you get a new context for `IFoo` and `IBar` and you will not know that they are injected into `MyService`.

e.g.

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<FooA>().WhenInjectedInto<MyService>();
Bind<IFoo>().To<FooB>().WhenInjectedInto<MyOtherService>();
```

will not work in the second case.

Comment: Picking the constructor is useful if there are two with the same parameter name and different types, in which case, Ninject will throw an exception. eg. `Foo(int x)` and `Foo(string x)`

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that you use the Inject method to keep the service context E.g. `ToConstructor(x => new FooA(x.Inject<BarA>()))` instead of doing `x.Context.Kernel.Get<BarA>`