# Ninject bind .Net Dictionary

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I want to bind IDicitionary<> to Dictionary<>. I tried the following binding:

```
Bind(typeof (IDictionary<,>)).To(typeof (Dictionary<,>));
```

Ninject sees the copy constructor, and tries to use it - which leads to a cyclic dependency.

How do I correctly specify this binding?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve here? What's the use for you to inject an empty dictionary into consumers? Do note that a `Dictionary<K, V>` is not a service, it's just a data object. A DI container is built for composing object graphs that consist of services (that contain behavior); not data objects.

Comment: It helps unit testing. In production, I want it to start with an empty container (which could be allocated with new, sure, but it doesn't matter). For tests however, it might make sense to pass a pre-populated one so I can test specific things without having to setup.

Comment: But with what data do you want to fill it during testing?

Comment: Whatever is appropriate for the test. I might also pass in a mocked dict.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to do is a smell. The dictionary is much to generic and makes your application completely dynamic (just as if you're doing late binding). If you show a concrete case for when and how you want to use this dictionary, we can show you a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround and two solutions i can think of (pick the one which suits you best):

- Create your own Dictionary `MyDictionary<,> : Dictionary<,>` (with only a single parameterless ctor) and `Bind(typeof (IDictionary<,>)).To(typeof (MyDictionary<,>));`
- Adapt the binding to: `this.Bind(typeof(IDictionary<,>)).ToMethod(ctx => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(ctx.GenericArguments)));`
- Adapt the binding to `this.Bind(typeof(IDictionary<,>)).ToConstructor(ctx => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(ctx.Context.GenericArguments)));`

For the difference between `.ToMethod()`and `.ToConstructor()` see: [What's the difference between .ToConstructor and .ToMethod in Ninject 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777475/whats-the-difference-between-toconstructor-and-tomethod-in-ninject-3)

Comment: But I don't want my own dict, I want the .Net IDictionary<>.

Comment: These are three separate solutions / workarounds. Pick the one most to your liking. (Sorry for not specifying this clearly)

Comment: btw., since i suggested inheriting from the `Dictionary` class - not the `IDictionary` interface - one could argue how much this would be your own implementation - you would not even need to write one additional line except for the class definition. But i would agree that it is still smelly.